# Url Forwarding without Iframe

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, forwarding

Some background on the problem :

We have our website setup for a domain already, lets call it X.com now we have purchased another domain Y.com and have done a URL Forward to X.com using Masking, such that when some one visits Y.Com the address bar will show Y.com put the website shown will be from X.com

The problem :

when using masking the webpage gets loaded within an Iframe. This is causing lot of problems like in IE page always loads in Quirks mode as the DOC Type is not there on the outer page, etc.

Is there a way to Keep the domain masking by not load an Iframe ?

We have tried the (top = self) javascript check and then set the href to self but that breaks the masking and shows X.com on the address bar.

Please guide us on how to get the contents from the IFrame that the URL Forwarding has created and put it in the top level window, or else is there any other solution to such a problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best and cleanest way to do this is at server level. If you're unfamiliar with your server set up, I strongly recommend you contact your hosting provider and explain your requirements.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Is is possible to achieve the requirements using a Server side script (php) ? Our Domain and Hosting are with two different providers, at the domain provider where we have set up the url forwarding, there is no such option to turn off the Iframe.

Comment: The fact that your domain and hosting are separate is not a problem. Contact your hosting provider and explain to them that you wish to point a new domain to your existing site, setting it up as an alias. They'll ask you to change the name servers of your new domain to point to their servers (and match your original domain), and they should be able to set up the aliasing for you. No server side technology would be able to help in this situation. However, I really should have mentioned that having two websites with the same content could result in Google penalising you for content duplication.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try breaking my head with the hosting providers they have a very poor customer service.